# FabricJS bold, italic style is not working in ITexts

Tags: angular, canvas, styles, fabricjs, textstyle

I am using fabricJS 3.0.0 and 2.7.0, but both version doesn't support bold and italic style on ITexts.

what I have tried is here:

```
1. this.canvas[0].getActiveObject().setSelectionStyles({fontWeight:'bold'});
   this.canvas[0].renderAll();

2. this.canvas[0].getActiveObject().set('fontWeight', 'bold');
   this.canvas[0].renderAll();
```

But none of them applying bold or italic,
can anyone give suggestion or patch for canvas please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [setSelectionStyles](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html#setSelectionStyles) then you need to select some text first or pass as parameter, and setting styles directly to text object will result to apply whole text.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text = new fabric.Text('Hello Fabricjs');
canvas.add(text);
setTimeout(function(){
  var selectionStart = 2,
  selectionEnd = 8;
  text.setSelectionStyles({fontWeight:'bold',fontStyle:'italic' }, selectionStart, selectionEnd);
  //text.set('fontWeight', 'bold');
  canvas.renderAll();
},1000)
```

```css
canvas{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='c'></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks durga for your reply, but not working, it is applying underline to texts but bold & italic is not working either,

Comment: @PiyushDholariya check added italic also

Comment: Thanks a lot but don't know not working bold and italic, I have put same code that you gave, I am using 3.0.0 version, underline is working fine.

Comment: @PiyushDholariya I am also using 3.0.0 in this snippet. You create a fiddle/snippet add in the question stating the issue.